# XFS Filesystem Backward Compatibility

Tags: linux, centos, xfs

I have been running a server for the past couple of weeks with CentOS-7 and it has worked out quite well. The current kernel version is:

```
3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
```

This machine has 40TB of storage provided by an internal hardware raid, which is formatted as an xfs volume.

In order to support an older software, I have decided to downgrade to CentOS 6.7. Which unfortunately, hasn't worked out as expected.

The system refuses to mount the file-system complaining about a bad super block on the file-system. During the manual mount, I noticed these errors using `dmesg`

```
kernel: XFS: bad version
kernel: XFS: SB validate failed
```

This only happens with 6.7. Everything works once boot into the older installation( Centos 7)

My current fix is to move the data to a different location and initialize the file-system again.Any ideas?

Comment: The newest kernel 4.10.  You should work on upgrading your ancient software instead of downgrading.

Comment: would running the older software in a VM or container be an option? Seems much more maintainable.

Comment: XFS support is built-in to the kernel.  If you can downgrade the other stuff, and leave the kernel version, and the xfs tools package in the current version it might work.